# How to construct a class defined in another file with g++?

Tags: c++, class, linker, g++

I have a simple question regarding using classes defined in the `#include`ed file. I have three files, class.cc, class.h and user.cc. I'm trying to use a class defined in class.cc in the file user.cc, but got an error I would like to understand (not just solve).

Here are the files:

## class.cc

```
class myclass {
  public:
    myclass() : nb(1) {};
    int nb;
    int myfunc();
};

int myclass::myfunc() {
  return 42;
}
```

## class.h

```
class myclass {
  public:
    myclass();
    int nb;
    int myfunc();
};
```

## user.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "class.h"

int main() {
  myclass example;
  std::cout << example.myfunc() << "class works too.";
}
```

What I do is create an object file for main.cc (main.o) and class.cc (class.o) and a static library class.a. Then when I try to link everything with:

```
g++ -o user user.o class.a
```

I get the following error:

```
user.o:user.cc:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `myclass::myclass()'
user.o:user.cc:(.text+0x15): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `myclass::myclass()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I understand that somehow user cannot see where the myclass constructor is defined, but I do not understand why not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class.h should not be repeated inside class.cc.  Instead, class.cc should do `#include "class.h"` at the top.  Then you simply need to recognize that you'll be missing your constructor definition, so either make it inline in class.h as you did in class.cc before, or define it the regular way, out of line, in class.cc.

You should never copy-paste one file into another in C or C++.  That's exactly what #include is for!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'm new here, so could I ask you why do you think the question has been downvoted?

Comment: Your question has probably been downvoted for being uninteresting and lacking the basics of c++ programming. If you are new to c++ thats somewhat expected. Be prepared to be downvoted a lot.